# Is using a class which sole purpose is to group 2 (very much related) objects together considered a good idea?

Tags: java

I can't find any information on this anywhere and was wondering whether such a use of a class is considered bad practise or not.

Let me explain. I have a class `ToDecimalConverter` which converts an integer from any base to decimal. However, I now need to add the functionality to also convert fractions. As such, I abstracted the integer conversion into a separate class and created a new class with the purpose of converting fractions. (Code isn't finished so I just added some comments to explain)

```
public class ToDecimalConverter {
    private IntegerToDecimalConverter integerConverter;
    private DoubleToDecimalConverter doubleConverter;

    public double convert(String number, int baseNumber) {
        this.integerConverter = new IntegerToDecimalConverter();
        this.doubleConverter = new DoubleToDecimalConverter();

        number = this.removeZerosAtBeginningOfNumber(number);

        // split the number into integer and fraction so they can be used below:

        int decimalInt = this.integerConverter.convert(integerNumber, baseNumber);
        double decimalDouble = this.doubleConverter.convert(fractioNumber, baseNumber);

        // add them together and return them
    }
}
```

Now, except for the methods that remove the zero's from the start of a number and the method that splits the number into integer and fraction (both of which can easily be abstracted into their own class), the `ToDecimalConverter` class does nothing but group the integer and fraction converters together.

When searching online, I don't see a lot of classes being used like this. Should this be avoided or not? and if so, what are alternatives?

This meant as a more general question, the above is just to explain what I mean.

Edit: Or should I see it as a sort of mini GoF Facade pattern?

Comment: Composing different classes in general is not bad, see [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). However, I don't understand why it makes sense to compose the two classes in your question, especially the "add them together and return them" comment. Your method is supposed to return an `int`, but an int plus a double is a double. What is `ToDecimalConverter`, `IntegerToDecimalConverter` and `DoubleToDecimalConverter` supposed to do?

Comment: How about abandoning your efforts and just use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: @Sweeper My bad, it is supposed to return a double, not an int. hadn't gotten round to changing that yet. Anyway, the reason they are in different classes is because the process for converting an int and a fraction is rather different. As such, they are to be splitted, converted separately, and then put back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going into the specifics of what your class is doing, there indeed value in grouping several or many function/classes together to from a single unified API.

This is called the [Facade design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

The intent is that instead of relying on your client to have to know of the various classes/objects you use internally to achieve a feature and to have to look all over the place inside your implementation code is that you put in place a single entry point for given feature/set of feature. It is much better for discoverability & documentation.

Also this way, you ensure to only provide the public API that is only one or a few classes that make the facade while the implementation remains hidden and can change at any time.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with it by default, but I would guess that you could achieve the same result with two methods. something like:

```
public int convertFromInt(String number, int baseNumber) {
    int theConvertedInt = 0;
    //Really cool convertion
    return theConvertedInt;
}

public double convertFromFraction(String number, int baseNumber) {
    double theConvertedInt = 0;
    //Really cool convertion
    return theConvertedInt;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that a lot of this conversions are already done by Java native classes like `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `Integer`, `Decimal`, `Double`, the `Math` package and so on.

Comment: This solution is much better and provide the same level of grouping if both methods are implemented in the same class ToDecimalConverter

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but what if the conversions were significantly more complex? Then a separate class would be wise right?

Comment: Checkout the YAGNI principle of extreme programming : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it. You should always follow the separation of concerns principle. And usually if they are different they should be separated. But that applies mostly to business logic. If you think about it, has you said, you have one concern: ConvertToInt. Everything else are different inputs (that may lead to different algorithms)

Comment: Now that I think about it, it would be rather elegant to have a static class and just do something like ToDecimal.fromFraction(...) And so on

Comment: I meant: *you have one concern: ConvertToDecimal

Comment: Thanks, will play around with that :)